# change Url when component renders with react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Is there a way in react router that whenever some components renders the url changes accordingly.

One way which I know is to place `window.history.pushState('', '', '/componentUrl');`  in the `render function` of the component

Is there any better way to accomplish it within the `route` other than `path` props in `Route` because `path= 'someurl'` means whenever `someurl` is accessed `someComponent` should render

But in the other way round whenever `someComponent`  renders urls should change to `someurl` I'm taking this senerio in context of conditional rendering inside a `component`.

Comment: how are you rendering that component

Comment: I'm rendering different components in a component on the basis of state like if state == 'a' render Acomponent  if state == 'b' render `Bcomponent` by this way component is rendering but url is not changing

Comment: The URL should drive the rendering of components. The app state and components shouldn't drive the URL. I'd instead look at changing the URL to then render this component.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the URL when the component is rendered Consider a case where you are rendering this component within nested child of another component, You would change the URL and now suppose you have the same component reused 3 different points then you would be changing the URL from 3 different components which is incorrect. Instead you should let URL drive your component rendering

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing to know when using react-router is that:

> The **path** attribute defines the route URL and **component** attribute
>   defines the component for this route.

I would suggest having a read through [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-react-apps-the-complete-guide). Best practice suggest, just like Matt Derrick suggested in the comments that the URL should drive the rendering of components.

Since you have Acomponent and Bcomponent that render based on the state I would suggest you then have 2 different URLs to accompany that. So when state changes to be ==='a' then you will jump to /aURL, when the state changes to be ==='b' then you will jump to /bURL.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: dats cool jump `to /aUrl`  mean `window.history.pushState('', '', '/aUrl)` ??

Comment: yes or in the appRoutes initialise something like  { path: '/aUrl',
    component: Acomponent
  }

Comment: this is what I have done , looking for a solution like pass a callback function in the `router` itself which will execute when a component renders , so that this jump url will be handled by the `router` itself . I don't know weather it is possible with `react-router-dom` .

Comment: In that case you will need something like state in the router. Maybe have a look at this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-state-router